# Problem in Veifying Smart Contract On Testnet

Tags: ropsten, oracles, rinkeby, contract-verification

I'm not able to verify my smart contract on Rinkeby and Ropsten Testnet Network.

Rinkeby Link - https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x029798a8c21050cbaaa2d5ecbd5e06622b602b82

Ropsten Link - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe25a62f72b5415977e1bbcc8eb1c1bc787341db3

**Important:**
I'm using oraclize services in my smart contract.

I have recently noticed that when I remove/comment oraclize related lines from my contract. It get's verified successfully. But I can't verify my contract when Oraclize is implemented!

Comment: Can you elaborate what issues are you facing?

Comment: You'll have to give more details as to what you've tried that has failed. However a couple of suggestions, make sure you are using the proper compiler version and optimization settings in etherscan when verifying the contract. I have had problems verifying contracts build with IDE tool kits. I find the beest way is to compile yourself with solc

Comment: @hextet Kindly let me know what other information is needed. I have been gone through the process before for some of my projects but this time I'm getting an error saying, "Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI". I'm unable to figure out the reason behind this. I tried to redeploy the contract and filled the verifying fields carefully but still got same error. Please help!

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Hi Prashant. Please see above reply and let me know what information is needed so that I can provide you with that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use Parity node by chance to deploy your contract?

Comment: @hextet No. I used Remix IDE to deploy my contract.

Comment: You need to include the contract code for oraclize as well.

Comment: @hextet Remix does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling with Remix, you likely just used the oraclizeAPI import statement. However, for verifying with etherscan, you need to have the whole plaintext code there in replacement of the import statement.

Likewise, ensure you've set the exact Solc version it was compiled with. There were some updates to the Oraclize API in the last few days, so beware of that as well when copying the plain text over, you may need to copy it from an earlier commit. If you continue to have trouble, you can contact Oraclize on their gitter channel https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api, and ask someone there to verify it for you, assuming you are able to provide the exact code and compiler you deployed it with.